# retweet with oauth c#

Tags: c#, api, oauth, twitter

I have tried to use [twitter api to retweet a status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/retweet/%3aid) , and use below code to send a post request

```
  webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/241259202004267009.json") as HttpWebRequest;
               webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
               webRequest.Method = "POST";
               webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 


webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxx\", oauth_nonce=\"xxx\", oauth_signature=\"xxxx\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1352642106\", oauth_token=\"xxxx\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"");

  requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
  requestWriter.Write(string.Empty);
  requestWriter.Close();
```

The user is authenticated with my twitter application in previous step but the above code do simply nothing and even do not returning any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `webRequest.GetResponse()` to actually send the request.

Comment: thanks , when I try to read the response I get (401) Unauthorized error , should I add any other parameter to it ?